# Youtube HTML5 green screen and beep sound

Tags: firefox, video, youtube

I am trying to get rid of Flash (using Flasblock) in my Firefox but I have a problem with YouTube.

After blocking it Firefox switched YT player to HTML5 but there is only 360p resolution available!

I searched in the internet to find a solution and I've tried changing few options in about:config to look like this:

- media.mediasource.enabled;  true
- media.mediasource.mp4.enabled;  true
- **media.mediasource.webm.enabled;  true**
- media.mediasource.whitelist;  true
- media.fragmented-mp4.enabled;  true
- media.fragmented-mp4.exposed;  true
- media.fragmented-mp4.ffmpeg.enabled;  false
- media.fragmented-mp4.gmp.enabled;  false
- **media.fragmented-mp4.use-blank-decoder;  true**

And when I go to https://www.youtube.com/html5 Everything is OK but when I try to play some video on YT I get a green screen and a beep sound.

But now I can choose the resolution.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

It works fine in Chrome

Comment: Could you open https://www.youtube.com/html5 in Firefox and see if everything is supported? it works fine in my Firefox. you might have an outdated version on your computer.

Comment: I have the newest version of Firefox. This is how it looks it youtube.com/html5: http://imgur.com/YsMw9Qk. Afer I change these 2 entries in about:config it's all supported but I have green screen and beep sound...

Comment: Try reinstalling Firefox. I have the most recent version of it as well, yet I support everything except the bottom-right option. you need to at least support H.264 video for Youtube to work.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to use a flash blocker, just install it from your PC entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the option `media.fragmented-mp4.use-blank-decoder` to `false`, this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Yes. I have already figured it out. But thanks anyway :)